# Table in IE 8 is not working properly

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

This is my following table which is not working in IE 8.

The problem is when I am scrolling the table, the first column is getting fixed and remaining rows are scrolling above the first column. This is probably only in IE 8; it is working fine in Chrome and Firefox.

```
<table border=0 id="dataTable0" class='table_data' style="position:absolute; margin:0;table-layout:auto" width=100%>
   <syn:outputData outputdata="#{DocDetailsBean.paraList}" ></syn:outputData>
</table>
```

This is my CSS file:

```
.table_data {
   background-color:#F3F3F3;
   color:#666666;
   text-align:left;
   font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
   font-size:11px;
}
```

Comment: please give an example of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add table-layout: fixed to the 's style. Without it, applying width to a table cell is interpreted as min-width (a carryover from when min-width didn't exist)

I found two ways to solve this problem in IE8.

```
   1)   Adding extra td element of width: 0px to tr's of thead and tbody.
```

[IE8 demo](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/X8FSw/17/show/)

```
   2)   Adding a hidden letter to content of after pseudo selector.

tr:after{
    content: ".";
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

I added the above in conditional css. because the problem was only in IE8. (I haven't tested in IE9+)

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
     <style>
         /* the above css code here */
     </style>
<![endif]-->
```

[IE8 demo](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/X8FSw/17/show/)

I used the latter one because it is simple.

Comment: when i am using that , scroll is not working table is getting fixed , i want it to scroll ...  it is working in chrome but not in  IE8